# how to open a modal and switch the iframe src inside the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, angular

I have a modal in my application which currently opens using bootsrap:

```
<div class="modal full-page fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="fullpageModal">
    <div class="full-page-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
         <iframe src="http://www.example.com/id/1"></iframe>
```

In my HTML I have a button attached to a function:

```
<button (click)="initPlay(2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fullpageModal" >PLAY</button>
```

At present bootstrap opens the modal and Angular handles the click.

**What needs to happen is this:**

1. User clicks on button
2. The iFrame URL src is updated according to the button clicked
3. The modal is made visible.

**What I think I need to do is this:**

1. Remove the opening of the modal from bootstrap and hand this to Angular2
2. On button click the function updates the iframe src
3. The function then opens the modal (or hands this back to Bootstrap?)

**My questions:**

1. What is the best method to update the iframe src? Maybe to include a variable: {{iframeSrc}} and to update this after click?
2. What is the best way to handle modal opening?

Thank you!

Comment: Using angular with bootstrap's js is probably going to be a mess.  You could look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ as they've already done the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

Well this turned out to be really simple.

I created two functions:

```
initPlay(id) {
    this.iframeSrc = "http://example.com/game/" + id;
}

clearPlay() {
    this.iframeSrc = "";
}
```

I left bootstrap to manage the modal open and close and simply used the Angular2 (click) method to initiate the src change.

I added a "loading" class to the iframe to show that action is taking place.

Thats it.